# How to send an email in GAE on behalf of a yahoo, hotmail, or .edu user?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email, gmail

On GAE, a non-gmail user can create a Google Account using their non-gmail email and log into a google app engine application. However, sending from that email does not appear to work all the time.

For example, suppose foobar@yahoo.com creates a google account and they log in. Then, GAE should be able to send email from foobar@yahoo.com during a user request.

The problem is that this does not appear to work for yahoo email accounts and others. In my experience, only the following users can have email sent on their behalf:

- Currently logged in **gmail** users
- Currently logged in users with **emails that run on google apps**
- Administrators

However, you **cannot** send email on behalf of users with the following email address:

- yahoo and hotmail users
- .gov or .mil users
- most .edu users, although I think some schools use google apps and they work.

If I send from those email addresses, I get the following error:

```
   message.send();
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/mail.py", line 799, in send
    raise ERROR_MAP[e.application_error](e.error_detail)
InvalidSenderError: Unauthorized sender
```

Am I missing something here?

I know there are similar questions out there on this topic but I don't think they nail them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application has no right to originate email from addresses you don't own.

Doing so is called spoofing and there has been a lot of work done in the last 8 years to prevent spoofing: DKIM, SPF...

If you need to send email you need to have your own email address(es)/domain to send the email from for this application and you'll need to handle bounces as well.

---

Update:

### Google Accounts

Google accounts can be created using 3rd party domain email addresses (e.g. hotmail, yahoo, *.edu, etc). There will be an email confirmation step to verify the email address, but there may be no greater relationship than this. The email address is the "username" and there's a password created with Google that has nothing to do with the 3rd party domain.

Google accounts don't have to have a mail service component. You can create a Google account and not have Gmail.

### Google email on a 3rd party domain

Google Apps can be run "on" 3rd party domains, this can, but not necessarily include Google email.

Google email could be run on any domain without any other "Apps", they offer email outsourcing which is quite attractive to the Education sector. In this scenario, Google is authoritative for email for that domain.

### On behalf of mailing

Google email has the functionality to set up "On Behalf of" emailing. This requires configuration. A confirmation email is sent to the target account. Once created the email is sent using the originating account's email address in the `mail envelope`, so any delivery status messages (delays, rejections) will be returned to this account. The originating email address will also be in the `sender header`. The address that you're sending on behalf of will appear in the `from header` in the messages, but otherwise, with regards to security settings and validation, it's a Google email from Google.

A quick search has returned some tech blog websites that suggest that they are considering retiring this feature in favour of supporting third party SMTP services.

### Third party SMTP server

So someone could configure their Google Email account with the SMTP server, username and password of their mail service provider and use it to send email via their Google mail interface through the valid servers of their mail service provider. This email would therefore genuinely "originate" from that domain's infrastructure.

---

I've not read the documentation for this GAE function to send email. However, I can see that if someone is signed into their Google account and that account has a mail service, then it could be possible to send email from that account using an API.

However, Google will not generate email "From" 3rd party domains for which it has not been assigned authority over. The email would not be valid; it would be "spoofed". It may not comply with a variety of security enhancements, could be used maliciously and would bring them into disrepute.

I hope this makes the situation clearer for you.

If the documentation is lacking in this regard, it could be that those who wrote it, being so familiar with email, might find it hard to imagine someone would think it were possible.

Comment: Why is it spoofing if the user is logged in and specifically requests to send the email on their behalf? Also, why would it work from gmail addresses but not yahoo addresses?

Comment: Because you're not their email service provider. I'll assume that GAE has a sending api for gmail accounts, because Google wrote and run them both. Google won't let you submit email "from" a yahoo address because Google isn't authoritative for that domain

Comment: What you're saying makes sense, although it's a bit speculative. I would love some confirmation from the google team. It isn't mentioned in the docs and it feels like a bug.

Comment: Trust me on this, I've been a mail admin for an enterprise and intimately familiar with email for longer than I care to remember.

Comment: I don't disagree with you, but the docs suggest otherwise. "The sender address must be one of the following types: ...
The address of the user for the current request signed in with a Google Account."

Comment: It's not a bug. The common element shared by Gmail users, Google Apps users, and registered administrators is that Google can verify that the logged in user actually controls the email address they want to send from. For Gmail and Google Apps, Google controls the authentication. For registered administrators, the user has clicked an activation link sent by Google to their external email. Google can't make the same claim for a random Hotmail or Yahoo! user.

Comment: This is making less sense and I think it's a bug. Two points. First, if a Yahoo! user creates a Google Account with a Yahoo! email address,  an activation email will be sent to the Yahoo! email address. The Google Account will not be activated until the user authenticates by clicking the link. Thus, Google can be sure the Yahoo! user has control over the email address specified in their Google Account. Second, even in gmail, you can send from a Yahoo! email address as long as you authenticate that you own it.  So Google does send email on behalf of Yahoo! email addresses directly from gmail.

Comment: That particular sending on behalf of uses an ENVELOPE FROM of the gmail address and perhaps also SENDER HEADER, the 3rd part email address goes in the FROM HEADER. If the user doesn't have a google-based email account this isn't possible.

Comment: Anyone who doesn't agree with Matt should have a go at setting up DomainKeys or SPF records for their domain, once you see how this works it will become clear why google can never send mail from domains they are not authorized to do so. Google *could* try and get agreements with other providers, but they'll never get them all, so they might as well not try.

Comment: It's not that I don't agree, I just don't understand. So can you explain why you can "send email as" from a Yahoo! email address from within gmail?

Comment: I did in my previous comment. Except I had a typo "3rd part" should be "3rd party".

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot. Is it possible to use the method you described from within Google App Engine? (i.e. access the ENVELOPE FROM headers from within google app engine)

Comment: Given the many different ways Google can have a relationship with an email address / domain, I can see how it might be confusing. I've expanded a lot on what I've said in these comments in my answer above. I've not looked at the GAE mail API, but the `ENVELOPE FROM` isn't a header, it is the name used to refer to the email address supplied after the `MAIL FROM` command within SMTP (i.e. the transmission of email).

Comment: Thanks for putting the time into this!

Comment: You are most welcome and it's nice that it's appreciated! However, I'd be lying if I denied that my relationship with SO was occasionally along the lines of [Duty Calls](http://xkcd.com/386/)...

Comment: FYI, you may want to take a look at that last answer. I think Google did change something. This was possible recently.

Answer (score 2):

For me it looks like Google has changed something. I've had an application running 1,5 years without problems (and changes) but suddenly on 2011-05-03 sending emails for example on behalf of Yahoo users stopped working.

This change also affected other non-Google (non-developer users).

Comment: I looked over my old logs. I can confirm that I was able to send email on behalf of non gmail users as late as April 17, 2011.

Comment: The SDK release notes at http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes mention new restrictions:

We have added two restrictions to the Mail API to improve the reliability of the service for all application.
Emails must be sent from email accounts managed by Google (either Gmail or a domain signed up for Google Apps).
Reduced the number of free recipients per day from 2000 to 100 for new applications.

Unfortunately Google haven't updated any of their other docs to reflect this.

Comment: James: You should write that up as an answer, because that is the right one. Thanks for the help, I just ran into this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If foobar@yahoo.com creates a Google account and logs in, you will be able to send on behalf of their Gmail user, but not their Yahoo user. Same for Hotmail. As for .gov, .mil or .edu, there's nothing special about these TLDs. If they are Google Apps domains, you can send from them, otherwise you cannot.

Note, though, that you can [specify a Reply-To address](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/emailmessagefields.html) when sending mail. This can be any email address whatsoever, so if you use a reply-to address of foobar@yahoo.com on outbound mail and the recipient clicks reply, this should be the address that's populated as the recipient.